# Test not passing when db context n separate using blocks

Tags: unit-testing, ef-core-2.0

I trying to do in memory ef core testing.

I have something similar to this:

Startup

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostgresConnection"), x=>x.UseNetTopologySuite()))
            .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Test method

```
 public void Add_writes_to_database()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Add_writes_to_database")
                .Options;

            // Run the test against one instance of the context
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
            {
                var service = new BlogService(context);
                service.Add("http://sample.com");
            }

            // Use a separate instance of the context to verify correct data was saved to database
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(options))
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(1, context.Blogs.Count());
                Assert.AreEqual("http://sample.com", context.Blogs.Single().Url);
            }
        }
```

When the context is split into 2 using blocks like above it does not pass the test.

But when its all wrapped in one context it works ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Had to also iclude `InMemoryDatabaseRoot`

```
   var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    databaseRoot: new InMemoryDatabaseRoot())
                .Options;
```